Expected output in google colab but wrong output in Leet code
enter image description hereenter image description here
Here the same code gives correct output in google colab but shows wrong output in leetcode with the same inputs.
the code is supposed to take two sorted arrays as parameter. then merge the arrays in a sorted way and then return the median of the newly created sorted array.
here's the code
class Solution(object):
def findMedianSortedArrays(self, nums1, nums2):
    res = sorted(nums1 + nums2)
    if len(res) % 2 != 0:
        return(res[(len(res)//2)])
    else:
        return((res[(len(res)//2)]+res[(len(res)//2)-1])/2)
a = Solution()
a.findMedianSortedArrays([1,2], [3,4])

leet code problem name : median of two sorted array (hard)

please format your code and post a description of what this code is supposed to do

It's super hard to read with no formatting.
But pasting your code, formatting it to valid python, and running on leetcode works as expected for the findMedianSortedArrays([1,2], [3,4]) test case shown in your screenshot.
By any chance did you change something in the code after the failed test case?
For example, one possibility could be if you were doing integer division in the else case before and now corrected it to float division.

im new here. sorry fo.r the formating problem. i did not change anything in the code before and after. you can check the screen shots @DarshanAS

It's because you're using Python version 2 -> Google Colab uses Python 3, In Leetcode set the language to Python3 and run it.
class Solution:
    def findMedianSortedArrays(self, nums1: List[int], nums2: List[int]) -> float:
       
        res = sorted(nums1 + nums2)
        if len(res) % 2 != 0:
            return(res[(len(res)//2)])
        else:
            return((res[(len(res)//2)]+res[(len(res)//2)-1])/2)


